# Give Unique Class to each table row in loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, loops, html-table

I have an PHP for loop; which looks at a number in database and outputs the tables rows to number of times.

Here is my HTML:

```
<?php
for($x=0; $x < 5; $x++){
$row_count =1;

  ?>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="ticktable">
<tr class=" <?php echo $row_count;  ?>">
<?php

for($w=0; $w < 5; $w++){

  ?>
<td>
     <img class="yellow-sign" src="http://www.backgroundsy.com/file/large/yellow-sign.jpg" width="100">
</td>
<?php

    }  
    ?>
    </tr>
  </table>
<?php
$row_count ++;
    }  
    ?>
```

The above code display this:

[image]

How I can assign unique class to each of the rows?

**Labelled Image**

[image]

Comment: now you get unique class name only. for eg: each row has unique $row_count.

Comment: I would like images in a row to have same class. For example images in first row should be like 'row-1', images in second row can be like 'row-2'. How I can assign class to images so that images in a row have same class.

Comment: do you need data in one table or in 5 tables because you are now creating 5 tables with one row and referring to them as "rows" and that's confusing

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
<?php foreach($data as $row) { ?>

    <tr id="data<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">   </tr>

<?php } ?>
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get unique class to `tr` then do this

```
for ($x = 0; $x < 5; $x++) {
$row_count = 1;
$randClass = rand(1111,9999).$row_count;
?>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="ticktable">
    <tr class="<?php echo $randClass; ?>">
        <?php

        for ($w = 0; $w < 5; $w++) {

            ?>
            <td>
                <img class="yellow-sign <?php echo $randClass; ?>" src="http://www.backgroundsy.com/file/large/yellow-sign.jpg" width="100">
            </td>
            <?php

        }
        ?>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
$row_count++;
}
```

`rand(1111,9999)` will generate random number between `1111` and `9999`

**EDIT**
i have also added `$row_count` so that the number can not be repeated even if there is large data. What I've done is: `<tr class="<?php echo rand(1111,9999).$row_count; ?>">`

**UPDATE**

first store the random string in a variable `$randClass = rand(1111,9999).$row_count;`

then echo out where you want the variable like this: 

`$randClass = rand(1111,9999).$row_count;`

and
 `<img class="yellow-sign <?php echo $randClass; ?>" >`

Comment: Thank you Regnlith. This is great. One final question. Since we have an unique class name, how can i than assign same class name to each element in <td> row. For example all elements in first row would have same class name "row11", element in second row of table would have different class bname "row12" etc...

Comment: are you trying to give class to `tr`, `td` or `img`?

Comment: `img`. Images in row should have same class. Next row images should have another same class. so as next row images should have another same class.

Comment: I have re-edited my question and added the heading "Labelled Image". Please look at that image, that should clear things up slightly.

Comment: you mean `tr` and `img` should have same class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code for you. Check this

```
 <?php
    $color_class[] = array("yellow-sign","red-sign","green-sign","blue-sign","black-sign");
    $row_count = 0;
    for($x=0; $x < 5; $x++){


 ?>

    <table class="table table-bordered" id="ticktable">
    <tr class=" <?php echo $row_count;  ?>">
 <?php

    for($w=0; $w < 5; $w++){

  ?>
    <td>
         <img class="<?php echo $color_class[$row_count];  ?>"
          src="http://www.backgroundsy.com/file/large/yellow-sign.jpg" width="100">
    </td>
 <?php

        }  
  ?>
        </tr>
      </table>
 <?php
    $row_count ++;
        }  
 ?>
```